# How to get two HTML buttons spaced horizontally

Tags: css, html

I need to get two HTML buttons horizontally with about 10/15 pixels space between them in the top right corner of the screen.

I tried many attempts but to no avail.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Um.. seems simple enough i guess..

```css
div{float:right}
button{margin:15px;}
```

```html
<div>
<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
<div>
```

(second button covered buy the editor - ignore that)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button>Button</button>
<button>Another button</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
}
```

if you add `display: block;` to an element they will be placed below each other, adding `margin-top: 15px;` creates the space between them.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple you just need a few css properties. I'll show you an example below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#rightCorner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
button {
    margin:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="rightCorner">
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```